# In IPython Widgets, how to update the DropDown widget with new value?

Tags: python, user-interface, jupyter-notebook

I created a DropDown widget:

```
self.foo_widget = widgets.Dropdown(description='Lorem ipsum', width=100)
self.foo_widget.options = ['Default', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

And I capture the `on_trait_change` event:

```
self.foo_widget.on_trait_change(self.handler, 'value')
```

Now in the handler function `handler`, I want set the DropDown value back to `'Default'`. But the following code only changes the value without updating the widget display. The DropDown still shows the original selection value (e.g., 'C') even though `print self.foo_widget.value` shows to be 'Default'.

```
self.foo_widget.value = 'Default'
```

Is this a bug of IPython Widget? What is the correct way to cause the update of the view?

In fact, for the list widgets, it seems I have to clear the options and assign options again to cause the widgets' display to update. Anyone has similar experience?

***Update:*** the answer by *nluigi* below works great. As shown in the following example.

```
class test(object): 
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo_widget = widgets.Dropdown(description='Lorem ipsum', width=100)
        self.foo_widget.options = ['Default', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
        self.foo_widget.on_trait_change(self.handler, 'value')
        display(self.foo_widget)

    def handler(self, name, old, new):
        print(self.foo_widget.value)
        print(self.foo_widget.selected_label)
        self.foo_widget.value = 'Default'
        self.foo_widget.selected_label = 'Default'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per the [specification](https://github.com/ipython/ipywidgets/blob/master/ipywidgets/widgets/widget_selection.py#L33) of the selection class, you must also set the `selected_label` attribute to `'Default'` to have the widget update:

```
self.dropDown.value = 'Default'
self.dropDown.selected_label = 'Default'
```